# Datatables doesn't work with android

Tags: android, jquery, datatable

I have a problem with datatables.

Everything works perfectly, but not on Android. With iOs, windows and any browser they work. But on Android I get this error:

> DataTables warning: table id=t_clienti - Ajax error. FOr more information about this error, please see http://datatables.net/tn/7

This is the HTML for the datatables:

```
    <link href="css/dataTables.bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <link href="css/dataTables.responsive.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <link href="css/dataTables.scroller.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">

 <div class="table-responsive" style="padding-right:20px">
                            <table class="table table-striped table-bordered responsive" cellspacing="0" width="100%" id="t_clienti">
                                <thead>
                                    <tr>
                                        <th class ="never">Id_cliente</th>
                                        <th class ="never">Id_medico</th>
                                        <th class ="never">Id_base</th>
                                        <th class ="never">Id_complementare</th>
                                        <th class ="never">Id_tutore</th>
                                        <th>Nome</th>
                                        <th>Cognome</th>
                                        <th>Data di nascita</th>
                                        <th>Telefono</th>
                                        <th>Indirizzo</th>
                                        <th>Medico</th>
                                        <th>Base</th>
                                        <th>Complementare</th>
                                        <th>Persona di riferimento</th>
                                    </tr>
                                </thead>
                            </table>
                    </div>

    <!-- DataTables !-->
<script src="js/jquery.dataTables.js"></script>
<script src="js/dataTables.bootstrap.js"></script>
<script src="js/dataTables.responsive.js"></script>
<script src="js/dataTables.scroller.js"></script>
```

My JS to declare the table:

```
$('#t_clienti').dataTable({
    ordering: true,
    searching: true,
     "order": [[ 0, "desc" ]],
    "processing" : true,
    "serverSide" : true,
    "ajax" : "scripts/Clienti/tabellaClienti.php",
    /*dom: "rtiS",*/
    "scrollY":        "300px",
    "scrollCollapse": true,
    "paging":         false
});
```

And Here I have tabellaClienti.php, I use that to use dataTables server-side. The ssp.class.php is a file that datatables give to do server-side.

```
 <?php
    require_once("../../Conn.php");
    include '../function.php';

    sec_session_start();
    if(login_check($mysqli) !== true) {
       header('Location: ../../login.php?error=1');
    }

$table = 'v_clienti';

$primaryKey = 'Id_cliente';

$columns = array(
    array( 'db' => 'Id_cliente', 'dt' => 0 ),
    array( 'db' => 'Id_medico', 'dt' => 1 ),
    array( 'db' => 'Id_base', 'dt' => 2 ),
    array( 'db' => 'Id_complementare', 'dt' => 3 ),
    array( 'db' => 'Id_tutore', 'dt' => 4 ),
    array( 'db' => 'Nome', 'dt' => 5 ),
    array( 'db' => 'Cognome',  'dt' => 6 ),
    array( 'db' => 'DataNascita',   'dt' => 7 ),
    array( 'db' => 'Telefono',   'dt' => 8 ),
    array( 'db' => 'Indirizzo',     'dt' => 9 ),
    array( 'db' => 'Medico',     'dt' => 10 ),
    array( 'db' => 'Base',     'dt' => 11 ),
    array( 'db' => 'Complementare',     'dt' => 12 ),
    array( 'db' => 'Tutore',     'dt' => 13 )
    );

require( '../ssp.class.php' );

echo json_encode(
    SSP::simple( $_GET, $sql_details, $table, $primaryKey, $columns )
);
?>
```

I think it's all.

Actually I can't understand why only in Android it doesn't work.

Thanks all.

Comment: when you say only in android - what browsers have you tried on what devices?

Comment: Oh well, I've tried on OnePlusOne with chrome and On an HTC (don't remeber the specific) with chrome.

Comment: have you tried with firefox? the link you provided for the error specifies a version of chrome in it's how to fix section, so it could be exacerbated by the browser rather than the device.

Comment: I'll try in 20 min, at the moment I play store doesn't work...

Comment: Even with firefox on OnePlusOne doesn't work